# CircleCI + Gradle + Heroku deployment

Tags: java, heroku, gradle, circleci

I'm trying to provide a continuous deployment with Gradle and Heroku but for some reason, the deployment step is not running.

[CircleCI Pipeline result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p7Mh.png)
[image]
I've already updated the circle ci with the Heroku key.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk

    working_directory: ~/repo

    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
      TERM: dumb

    steps:
      - checkout

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: gradle dependencies

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.m2
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: gradle test
deployment:
  staging:
    branch: master

    heroku:
      appname: my-heroku-app
```

Could you guys help me, please? Is the deployment step in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

You are using deployment configuration for [CircleCI 1.0](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/continuous-deployment-with-heroku/) but you are using [CircleCI 2.0](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/deployment-integrations/#heroku).

From the documentation for CircleCI 2.0:

> The built-in Heroku integration through the CircleCI UI is not
>   implemented for CircleCI 2.0. However, it is possible to deploy to
>   Heroku manually.

To deploy on heroku with CircleCI 2.0, you need :

1. add environment variables HEROKU_LOGIN, HEROKU_API_KEY, HEROKU_APP_NAME to your CircleCI project settings `https://circleci.com/gh/<account>/<project>/edit#env-vars`
2. create a private ssh key without passphrase and add it to your CircleCI project settings `https://circleci.com/gh/https://circleci.com/gh/<account>/<project>/edit#ssh` for hostname git.heroku.com
3. add steps in the .circleci/config.yml file with the fingerprint of your ssh key

> ```
>   - run:
>       name: Setup Heroku
>       command: |  
>         ssh-keyscan -H heroku.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
>         cat > ~/.netrc << EOF
>         machine api.heroku.com
>           login $HEROKU_LOGIN
>           password $HEROKU_API_KEY
>         EOF
>         cat >> ~/.ssh/config << EOF
>         VerifyHostKeyDNS yes
>         StrictHostKeyChecking no
>         EOF
>   - add_ssh_keys:
>       fingerprints:
>         - "<SSH KEY fingerprint>"
>   - deploy:
>       name: "Deploy to Heroku"
>       command: git push --force git@heroku.com:$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD:refs/heads/master
> ```